# Count number of intersections of many random walks in a graph

Tags: intersection, random-walk

I want to run k random walks from each node of a connected un-directed graph with length lambda. When two or more walks visit one node at a same time, they combine into one walk and continue as a single random walk until lambda steps finish. I want to know how many walks will be merged at the end of the lambda steps or at least know a good bound for it.

Comment: is this a directed or undirect graph?

Comment: un-direct graph